# AngularJS Long Polling - push result to list

Tags: angularjs, long-polling

Currently I can push long polling results to the $scope.newMsg variable, however I would like to add it to the messages list $scope.messages.push(msg).

This is my current app.js:

```
var messageApp = angular.module('messageApp', ['ngResource']);
messageApp.run(function(newMessagePoller) {});

messageApp.factory('messagesService', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/myapp/resources/message/all', {}, {
        query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true}
    });
});

messageApp.factory('newMessagePoller', function($http, $timeout) {
    var data = {response: {}};
    var poller = function() {
        $http.get('/myapp/newmsg').then(function(r) {
            data.response = r.data;
            $timeout(poller, 1);
        });
    };
    poller();
    return {data: data};
});

messageApp.factory('createMessageService', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/myapp/resources/message', {}, {
        create: {method: 'POST'}
    });
});

messageApp.factory('messageService', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/myapp/resources/message/:id', {}, {
        show: {method: 'GET'},
        update: {method: 'PUT', params: {id: '@id'}},
        delete: {method: 'DELETE', params: {id: '@id'}}
    });
});
messageApp.controller('messageCtrl', function($scope, newMessagePoller, createMessageService, messagesService, messageService) {
    $scope.messages = messagesService.query();
    $scope.newMsg = newMessagePoller.data;

    $scope.newMessage = function() {
        var newEntry = createMessageService.create($scope.message);
        $scope.messages.push(newEntry);
    };

    $scope.deleteMessage = function(msg) {
        messageService.delete({id: msg.id});
        $scope.messages.splice($.inArray(msg, $scope.messages), 1);
    };

    $scope.updateMessage = function(message) {
        messageService.update(message);
    };
});
```

I have tried passing the controller to the newMessagePoller:

```
messageApp.factory('newMessagePoller', function($http, $timeout, messageController) {
    var data = {response: {}};
    var poller = function() {
        $http.get('/basic-angularjs-ee/newmsg').then(function(r) {
            data.response = r.data;
            $timeout(poller, 1);
        });
    };
    poller();
    messagePoller.pushNewMessage(data.response);
});
...

$scope.pushNewMessage(msg) {
   $scope.messages.push(msg);
}
```

I guess my approach is wrong, any help would be much appreciated.

** Working code **
I have had to make the following changes to get the code working (thank you domakas):

```
messageApp.factory('newMessagePoller', function($http, $timeout) {
    var data = {data: ''};
    var poller = function() {
        $http.get('/myapp/newmsg').then(function(r) {
            data.data =  r.data;
            $timeout(poller, 1);
        });
    };
    poller();
    return data;
});
```

Assigned the response to the data attribute of the json structure.

```
$scope.$watch(
        function() { return newMessagePoller.data; }, 
        function(newMsg, oldMsg) {
            $scope.newMsg = newMsg;
            $scope.messages.push(newMsg);
        }
);
```

Added the $watch function to the controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to understand what is your ultimate goal here, but I think you should create watcher for your `newMessagePoller` in your controller and push message there:

```
$scope.$watch(function() { return newMessagePoller.data; }, function(new, old) {
    if(new !== old) {
        $scope.messages.push(new);
    }
});
```

Comment: basicly the server fills the long polling request with a new message (json). All that I want to do is add the new message to the list. What exactly is old?

Comment: This watch is constantly checking value of `newMessagePoller.data`, and in callback function variable `new` is new value of `newMessagePoller.data` and `old` is previous `newMessagePoller.data` value. The `if` statement here checks of value actually changed.

Comment: I have added it to the controller, however it doesn't seem to be working:     $scope.$watch(
            function() { return newMessagePoller.data; }, 
            function(newMsg, oldMsg) {
                $scope.newMsg = msg;
                $scope.messages.push(msg.response);
            }
    );

Comment: My mistake it is actually working for newMsg, oddly so it is not pushing to the list

Comment: You are pushing `msg.response` you should push `newMsg`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, however there was another mistake in my poller, instead of assigning the response date to response I should have simply assigned it to data in the json structure. (I have posted the working code in the question.